# Comparing string in file

Tags: html, c

I am trying to print this line of code to the HTML file when my file reads the character "form". However, I keep failing and I have no idea how to do it. Please help

```
fgets(str,999,p);

while (!feof(p)) {
    if (strstr("form", str) != NULL) {
        printf("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"gold\" value=\"%d\"", goldpieces);
    }

    printf("%s", str);
    fgets(str,999,p);
}

fclose(p);
return 0;
```

Comment: Likely because the _line_ from the file is `"form\n"`.  Try `strstr(str, "form")` to search for the occurrence of `"form"` in the line.  Is that what you are after?

Comment: basically I have  <form action=... method="get">
                        <input type="text" name="answer">
                        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
                </form>

and I want to add to this when writing. Your method is not working

Comment: "method is not working" is vague.  What output did you see?  What output was expected?

Comment: Sorry this question was very vague, I think I got it sorted out thanks